# Ember TransitionAborted when performing a full route transition with new query params

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Why does a TransitionAborted error get thrown when performing a full route transition when changing query params?

I am working off of the "[Opt-in to full transition via refresh()](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucanam/6054)" example provided at the bottom of the query parameters Ember guide (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

The only change I made was to log errors:

```
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
  Ember.Logger.assert(false, error);
});
```

Here is an updated JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/rerido/1/edit?console,output

If you click the "Change it" button, you'll see a TransitionAborted error thrown in the console.

I've been trying to upgrade Ember in my app from 1.7.0-beta.1+canary for some time now, but many of my QUnit tests fail when I run them all together. Most of my tests are fine if I run them in isolation. I suspect the TransitionAborted errors may be causing the test failures. However, I'm not sure if TransitionAborted exceptions are normal when performing full transitions. If anyone can confirm one way or the other, that would be very helpful in getting to the root cause of my problems, whatever they might be.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution to this yet. I tried to step through the code, but no luck yet. I've opened an issue on Github (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5566), and machty's been assigned to it! Crossing my fingers.

Comment: Some helpful info you can find here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12505

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem too today. I'm using Ember 1.11.1 and Ember-data 1.1.1-beta.16.1.

In my case the change in the query parameter doesn't affect the model's data but another query. So what I ended up doing was removing the `refreshModel: true` from my parameter in the route code, and I added an observer on the controller for that URL parameter. So when the controller detected a change in that queryParam variable, the controller called the function I needed to re-query my secondary model.

I'm not sure if this would fix the issue if the query parameter is tied to the route's model, as I haven't tried that yet in my code. It looks like from the github link in the comment above that there's a confirmed bug with this somewhere, so I am curious how that will end up.

Bryan